# MongoDB - Query nested objects in nested array with array of strings filter

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

So basically I need to filter my data with my own filter, which is array of strings, but problem is, that that exact field is inside nested object in array in DB. so, part of my Schema looks like this:

```
members: [
    {
        _id: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "Users" },
        profilePicture: { type: String, required: true },
        profile: {
            firstName: { type: String },
            lastName: { type: String },
            occupation: { type: String },
            gender: { type: String }
        }
    }
]
```

and my filter looks like this

```
gender: ["male","female"]
```

expected result with this filter is to get a team which has both male users and female users, if it has only male, or only female, it should not give me that team. but everything i've tried was giving me everything what included males and females even tho there were only male members.

what i've tried:

```
db.teams.find(members: { $elemMatch: { "profile.gender": { $in: gender } } })
```

This works only when there is one gender specified in the filter, and well, i know it must not work on what i am trying to achieve, but i dont know how to achieve it. any help will be appreciated

Edit: I've tried to do it in this way

```
db.teams.find({
    $and: [ 
        { members: { $elemMatch: { "profile.gender": gender[0] } } }, 
        { members: { $elemMatch: { "profile.gender": gender[1] } } } 
    ]
})
```

and this gives me result only when both filters are specified, however, if there is only one filter(either "male", or "female") it is giving me nothing.

Answer (score 0):

Use [$and](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/and/) operator instead of $in.

```
db.teams.find(members: {$elemMatch: {$and: [{'profile.gender': 'male'}, {'profile.gender': 'female'}]}})
```

Comment: This is not working. right now i am getting no result at all. with both two filters or one, result is still nothing

Answer (score 0):

This query works no matter how many elements you want to compare

```
db.teams.find({$and: [{'members.profile.gender': 'male'}, {'members.profile.gender': 'female'}]})
```

You need to dynamically generate the query before passing it to `find`, if you want to cover more than one case.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with the [`$all`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/all/#op._S_all) operator that finds docs where an array field contains contains all specified elements:

```
var gender = ['male', 'female'];
db.teams.find({'members.profile.gender': {$all: gender}});
```